# Почему глагол "зоревать" попал в исключения?

Tags: орфография

Какова орфографическая история   глагола "зоревать", почему он стал исключением, как он пишется сейчас (каким источникам следует доверять)?

**Из правил 1956 года:** Корень зар- пишется в словах заря, зарница, озарять (под ударением – зарево, лучезарный) и во всех образованных от них словах (озарение и др.); **корень зор- пишется под ударением** в отдельных словах и формах: зорька, зоренька, зорюшка, зори, зорь, зорю (бить, играть зорю).

**А каково значение слова?** Зоревать ― это не спать на заре, встречать зарю или зори? Или это спать на заре?

Примеры:

А это мы к утру итоги подобьем: кому горевать, а кому **зоревать и во сне** потягиваться. [М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 2 (1959)]

Долго **зорюешь**, Пантелей Прокофьич! ― шумели припотевшие косари (М. Шолохов).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Какова орфографическая история глагола "зоревать"...

Сегодня более правильно: ***заревать***.
Такое написание даётся в [**РОС**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), такое написание соответствует и правилам [**ПАС**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/#id-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%C2%A735):

> **§ 35.** ...***зар – зор.*** На месте безударного гласного пишется ***а.***

Из ***"Объяснительного русского орфографического словаря-справочника"*** (авт. Бешенкова Е. В., Иванова О. Е., Чельцова Л. К.; М., 2015):

> Слова ***заревать, зарянка, заревой*** изменили написание в словарях
>   последних десятилетий. С 1999 г. в академическом орфографическом
>   словаре даётся слово ***заревать.*** До 1974 г. словари рекомендовали
>   писать слово ***зорянка*** с корнем ***зор-.*** *"Орфографический*
>   *словарь русского языка"* в 13-м издании 1974 г. утвердил в качестве
>   нормативного написание ***зарянка.*** Слово ***заревой*** с 1991 г.
>   рекомендуется писать только с корнем ***зар-***, хотя в
>   орфографическом словаре 1974 г. приводились оба варианта, а в 1956 г.
>   было только ***зоревой,*** в словаре Д. Н. Ушакова ***заревой.*** Как
>   имя собственное утвердилось написание ***Зоревая пушка*** (в
>   Петербурге), хотя в общем случае пишется ***заревая пушка***. В
>   качестве примера приведём название рассказа В. Шукшина, которое до сих
>   пор пишется то ***"Заревой дождь"***, то ***"Зоревой дождь".***

Но... В стране демократия, и только потому, наверное, в ряде словарей у ряда авторов сохраняется написание с ***о: зоревать.***

Как быть при таком раздрае в словарях и учебниках школьникам?  См. [***"Полный справочник по подготовке и проведению единого государственного экзамена":***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=UK_DBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA170&dq=%22%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjshZrSwM7PAhXpbZoKHW_zAn0Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&f=false)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вопросы такие: ПАС, на который Вы указываете, это на самом деле редакция 1956 года (именно в отношении ЗАР/ЗОР), на сайте Грамоты.ру оба варианта проходят (зоревать - в словаре ударений, заревать - в орф. словаре.  В правилах Лопатина информации нет.  Вы говорите, что "заревать" появилось в словаре в 1999 году, а до этого писали "зоревать"? В правилах 1956 года это слово не упоминается, до 1956 года скорее всего была форма "зоревать", в Нацкорпусе встречается только это написание. Получается, что в 1999 году приказали перейти на новую форму, но не все послушались.

Comment: _**Sibylla**: Вопросы такие: ПАС, на который Вы указываете, это на самом деле редакция 1956 года_. === Простите, ничего не понял. Я привёл выдержку именно из ПАС. При чём тут Правила-56?

Comment: Я хотела сказать, что текст полностью совпадает, про "зоревать" информации нет ни в ПАС, ни  в правилах 1956 года.

Comment: _**Sibylla**: Я хотела сказать, что текст полностью совпадает..._ === Да не совпадает он. В Правилах-56 правила как такового о написании корней _зар/зор_ нет: есть только перечни (причём неполные) слов с этими корнями. В ПАС же правило сформулировано чётко: _На месте безударного гласного пишется **а**..._

Comment: _**Sibylla**: Получается, что в 1999 году приказали перейти на новую форму._ ===    
Да приказывать-то практически некому было. Кто сейчас использует это слово? Практически никто. А в правилах приходилось постоянно приводить его как исключение. Сейчас одним исключением стало меньше.

Comment: _**Sibylla**: А каково значение слова?_ === Я бы сформулировал его так: _зарю во сне встречать_.  Может, и не везде и не у всех авторов это слово употреблялось именно в таком значении… Не знаю.

Comment: Слово перешло на нелегальное положение, пропало из словарей, никто не знает, как его писать, вот и о его значении уже приходится догадываться по литературным текстам. И всё для того, чтобы мы грамотнее были,  исключений поменьше учили, да только грамотность не с того начинается.  И не упрощаем мы язык тем, что  "разобрались" с каким-то там малоценным словом, а делаем свою речь беднее и примитивнее.

Comment: _**Sibylla**_: И не упрощаем мы язык тем, что "разобрались" с каким-то там малоценным словом, а делаем свою речь беднее и примитивнее_. === Ну, **речь**-то от замены _**о**_ на -**а**_ в этом слове не пострадает: оба варианта звучат абсолютно одинаково.

Comment: Звучат одинаково, да пишутся по-разному,  так что письменная речь пострадает.

Comment: Ответ Цыбулько был справедлив 2 года назад, когда нужно было отнести слово к словам с чередующейся гласной или с проверяемой. Теперь же нужно еще и вставить букву. Причем в ответах - с буквой О. А в сочинение оценивают эксперты, они же школьные учителя. А в учебниках до сих пор "зоревать" в качестве исключения.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, справедливо было бы оставить слово "**зоревать**" (зори во сне проводить - такое написание интуитивно понятно, поскольку глагол несовершенного вида меньше ассоциируется с одной, конкретной "зарёй") в исключениях, как это зафиксировано напр. в старых добрых справочниках Розенталя. Вариант "*заревать*" может восприниматься как глагол несовершенного вида, образованный от "*зарев**е**ть*", т. е. со значением "*начинать реветь*". Нормотворчество составителей новых словарей здесь вряд ли можно обосновать фиксацией массово изменившегося написания столь редко употребляемого слова. Скорее, это просто попытка реабилитировать "спотыкающееся" правило, вогнав в него былое исключение.

Comment: Я согласна с Вашей оценкой глагола "зоревать", ему больше подходит форма ЗОР, ЗА - похоже на приставку, "зоревать"  по смыслу  больше связан с зорями, а не с зарей, интуитивно хочется написать "зоревать". А в толковых словарях это слово есть, у Ожегова например?

Comment: У Ожегова и Даля слово не находится; з**о**ревать есть в орф. словаре Лопатина - в сети ссылаются на издания 2011-2012 года: http://www.slovorod.ru/orth-lopatin/lop-z.htm

Comment: _**Alex_ander:** зоревать есть в орф. словаре Лопатина - **в сети ссылаются на издания 2011-2012 года**_ === В сети **врут**. Ну, или ошибаются. Нет у Лопатина в словаре, изданном в  2012 г. (4-е издание, исправленное и дополненное; рекомендовано Орфографической комиссией РАН 19 мая 2010 года), написания _**зоревать**_. Есть только _**заревать**_. Уж нравится оно кому-либо или не нравится, но есть только оно.